# Memory leak in UIWebView

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiwebview, instruments

I have a head(butt)ache last two days. A dodgy memory leak makes me Hulk.
A lot of leaks appear after loading any url request in custom UIWebView when profiling code on the simulator. But if I use a device like iPhone 5 there is just one leak.
The huge trouble is that Instruments does not show any line of **my** code.
I remember as I saw a great video tutorial to locate these leaks, but googling has no result in two days :(
Here is a simple [project](https://github.com/pomozoff/AKWebCoreLeaks) for Xcode 5, it leaks when webView property loaded an url request.

Screenshots: [one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/97ms1widv7j3bdl/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202013-10-11%2013.53.51.png), [two](https://www.dropbox.com/s/duu898mpw0y21d3/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202013-10-11%2013.55.47.png).

UPD: Added whole code.
UPD2: Tiny refactoring.

```
#import "AKViewController.h"

@interface AKViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation AKViewController

@synthesize webView = _webView;

#define MARGIN_WEB_VIEW_X 15.0f
#define MARGIN_WEB_VIEW_TOP 30.0f
#define MARGIN_WEB_VIEW_BOTTOM 25.0f

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (CGRect)makeRectForWebView {
    CGRect appFrame = UIScreen.mainScreen.applicationFrame;
    CGRect rectWebView = CGRectMake(MARGIN_WEB_VIEW_X,
                                    MARGIN_WEB_VIEW_TOP,
                                    appFrame.size.width - MARGIN_WEB_VIEW_X * 2,
                                    appFrame.size.height - MARGIN_WEB_VIEW_BOTTOM);

    return rectWebView;
}
- (void)presentViews {
    [self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    self.webView.frame = [self makeRectForWebView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
}
- (NSURLRequest *)makeLoginURLRequest {
    NSString *stringUrl = @"http://google.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[stringUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    return request;
}

#pragma mark - Properties

- (UIWebView *)webView {
    if (!_webView) {
        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.applicationFrame];
        _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    }

    return _webView;
}

#pragma mark - Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self presentViews];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[self makeLoginURLRequest]];
}

@end
```

HELP!

Comment: can you show some code? have you used ARC?

Comment: Try to set webview = nil in viewWillDisApper method.

Comment: I use ARC, leak appears when self.webView **loaded** a page. Not when it trying to leave.

Comment: Look code here: https://github.com/pomozoff/AKWebCoreLeaks/blob/master/AKWebCoreLeaks/AKViewController.m

Comment: try this , before loading a page stop earlier page .

Comment: There is no earlier page. But I tried and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're showing all of the code, so I'm going to guess that you may not be releasing the web view's delegate. The documentation for the `UIWebView` `delegate` property says:

> **Important:** Before releasing an instance of `UIWebView` for which you
>   have set a delegate, you must first set its delegate property to `nil`.
>   This can be done, for example, in your dealloc method.

Comment: Guys, I made a complete project especially for you and posted it to GitHub. Why you do not want to see there?

Comment: The leaks appear when UIWebView **loaded** a page! Not when it's leaving!